# Negative Lookahead within a random string

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to filter words which end on `Model` but do not end on `ViewModel`. There also needs to be at least 2 characters in front of `Model`

```
MyModel // - do match
MyViewModel // - do not match
```

So I thought this is easy and this negative lookahead should be good enough. But 
it's not working the way I want it to. It's matching `ViewModel` too.

```
^[a-z]{2,99}(?!View)Model$
```

[Example on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/owt4fi/1)

Comment: What is your flavor/language?

Comment: Also, can you share some more examples on what should be matched and what not?

Comment: I think you want a look behind.  `(?<!` not `(?!`

Comment: @zzxyz it seems you are right. although I don't understand why this is working. You might want to post it as answer.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/owt4fi/2

Comment: I always forget about the lookbehind :) post it as an answer @zzxyz

Comment: I'm happy for another answer to be accepted if there's a chance it helps me understand lookarounds better :)  I sort of *get* them at this point, but feel unable to articulate their behavior...which means I don't really get them :)

Comment: Not all regex flavors support lookbehinds. Please specify a language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern `(?!A)B` will always match on B because obviously you're not looking at an A and B simultaneously. To check what came before B, you can use a (negative) look-behind:

[`^[a-z]{2,99}(?<!View)Model$`](https://regex101.com/r/owt4fi/3)

So why didn't the lookahead work?

The matching goes like this (without the backtracking)

```
MyView       |  ^[a-z]{2,99}              // Match as much as we can 
             |              (?!View)      // No "View" ahead, so we're good
      Model  |                      Model // normal match
```

Comment: I knew lookahead was wrong, but not quite why...and I'm still not sure I get it with this answer.  I guess in the look ahead, `View` is sort of anchored against the stuff on the left...which is more or less "whatever"?

Comment: @zzxyz I added some details, does this help?

Comment: yes, thank you :)  I basically had the right idea, but this really cements it.

Answer (score 0):

You could match any wordcharacter zero or more times `\w*` followed by `ViewModel` and capture in a group 2 or more word characters `\w{2,}` followed by `Model`.

This way you match what you don't want, and you capture in a group what you do want.

Your match is in captured group 1.

[`\w*ViewModel|(\w{2,}Model)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/4SV5Cz/1)

**Details**

- `\w*` Match zero or more word characters
- `ViewModel` Match literally
- `|` Or
- `(\w{2,}Model)` Capture in a group 2 or more word characters followed by Model
- `\b` Word boundary

Answer (score 0):

Not all regex flavors support lookbehinds `(?<=...)` / `(?<!...)` like JS (Chrome has a support so far). But you could work around this using lookaheads:

```
\b(?!\w*ViewModel\b)\w{2,}Model\b
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pmv87T/3)

Breakdown:

- `\b` Match a word boundary
- `(?!` Start of negative lookahead

  - `\w*ViewModel\b` Word shouldn't end with `ViewModel`
- `)` End of lookahead
- `\w{2,}Model\b` Match entire word that ends with `Model`